# dynamic checklistbox in windowsform on c#

Tags: c#, forms, checkbox

i want to have a group of check boxes like CheckListBox with different back colores .
is there any way for me to have this group and edit at run time?

i use the code bellow but it is cant be in different back colors:

```
            foreach (var color in _colors)
            {
                var tmpCheckBox = new CheckBox
                                    {
                                       // Location = objLocation,
                                        BackColor = color,
                                        Text = color.Name
                                    };
                objLocation.X = objOffset;
                objLocation.Y += tmpCheckBox.Height + objOffset;
                clbColorAnalyzeResult.Items.Add(tmpCheckBox);
            }
```

just to mention this:
clbColorAnalyzeResult.Controls.Add(tmpCheckBox);
will not help because there is no scroll bar and i cant use the selected index!

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the checkbox to the `Controls` property of your form.

Maybe you will have to create you own custom list box and override the OnDrawItem method.
Something like this:

```
class MyCheckedListBox : CheckedListBox
    {
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: will not help because there is no scroll bar and i cant use the selected index (i want to use the benefits of a list)!.

Answer (score 1):

Do this!

You should add the checkboxes to a `Panel`, and set `AutoScroll` to true, to get the scrollbars. You can subscribe to the `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` event to determine which checkbox is selected.